# rpm -q -> query only the descripton

Tags: c++, linux, command-line, rpm

I can query the informations about a rpm-package with

```
rpm -qi <rpm-package-name>
```

Example-Result of a Query:

```
tfaa004:/sm/bin # rpm -qi expect-5.45-16.1.3.i586
Name        : expect
Version     : 5.45
Release     : 16.1.3
Architecture: i586
Install Date: Di 27 Jun 2017 15:31:08 CEST
Group       : Development/Languages/Tcl
Size        : 674166
License     : SUSE-Public-Domain
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Do 25 Sep 2014 11:42:26 CEST, Key ID b88b2fd43dbdc284
Source RPM  : expect-5.45-16.1.3.src.rpm
Build Date  : Do 25 Sep 2014 11:42:16 CEST
Build Host  : cloud120
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : http://bugs.opensuse.org
Vendor      : openSUSE
URL         : http://expect.nist.gov
Summary     : A Tool for Automating Interactive Programs
Description :
Expect is a tool primarily for automating interactive applications,
such as telnet, ftp, passwd, fsck, rlogin, tip, and more.  Expect
really makes this stuff trivial.  Expect is also useful for testing
these applications.  It is described in many books, articles, papers,
and FAQs.  There is an entire book on it available from O'Reilly.
Distribution: openSUSE 13.2
```

But I only want to query the Description. Is that possible?
The reason for that is that I want to process this information (the Description) in a C++ Program (I do this with popen()).

Maybe something like this:

```
rpm -qi -Description expect-5.45-16.1.3.i586
```

Comment: Asking for libraries is off-topic here on SO.  Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct sollution:

```
rpm -q --queryformat '%{DESCRIPTION}\n'  expect-5.45-16.1.3.i586
```

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT for openSUSE rpm output]:

## rpm -qi package_name | sed '1,/Description/d;/Distribution/,$d'

This will only print lines between "Description" and "Distribution"

[The below cmds work for RHEL distros]

I do not believe the "rpm" utility has a flag to only print out the "Description" field, but it's as simple as using a pipe :)

You could do:

## rpm -qi openssh-server-5.3p1-104.el6.x86_64 | awk '/Description/, 0'

Which will print every line after the pattern "Description" is found.

Or, if you're more inclined to use "grep":

## rpm -qi openssh-server-5.3p1-104.el6.x86_64 | grep -A20 'Description'

the "-A n" flag tells grep to print n lines After the pattern is found.

***Edit: you may also use "sed":

## rpm -qi openssh-server-5.3p1-104.el6.x86_64 | sed -e '1,/Description/ d'

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not really, because it is not specified how many lines the Description has.

Comment: As stated in my first example, you may use "awk" or "sed", which is independent of the number of lines after the pattern.

Comment: This gives me every line after Description:

Comment: But I think you are right, there is no flag for rpm to only print the description

Comment: What I understood from your request is that you want to query a certain rpm package and obtain its description as output... isn't that the case ?

Comment: So, why did you state: "This gives me every line after Description:. This is not correct. I only want the description." ? Everything after the "Description:" pattern is text characterizing the respective package...

Comment: It also gives me the Distribution too. That is the last line of the whole output. I don't want that.

Comment: Apologies, I did not notice the rpm output you provided was on SUSE, I was sharing solution for RHEL Edited, I think this will work for you.